# Mindfulness when sick?

Tags: mindfulness

I am trying to be mindful whenever I am not too absorbed in whatever i am doing and then I got sick. Everything stopped from fast to slow motion. I had time to watch myself being mindful, but then it occurred to me what I should be mindful off? Since I am physically sick now, should I repeat my current state of mind- 'I am sick', 'I am sick', 'I am sick' and this is so depressing or should I change my frame of mind to something positive - for future well being like ' I am getting better', 'I am getting better', 'I am getting better '.

Which is right way of being mindful? Being in Present or Hope for better future!!!

Answer (score 5):

Don't do either of those. When using the Mahasi Sayadaw method of noting, you should only note things that you are directly experiencing in the present. You don't directly experience sickness itself, but rather various symptoms such as tiredness, nausea, diziness, etc... Just note those individually as they come up. Or just note the movement of the abdomen or the posture, etc...

Answer (score 2):

are you getting sick because you practice mindfulness?   or you are sick and dont know where best to be mindful of?   If the later one, then you might want to read this [Gilana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.121.than.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just a note. If you focus on the "quality" of something, like sickness or happiness, then it gets reinforced. Consequently, obviously you're depressed.

Sickness or getting better is a quality of your physical being. This is harder than it sounds. Accept it as it is but don't bother with it much more than just taking your pills or resting. Just accept the current state without judging it's quality.

When you're sitting, sit. When you're standing, stand. This is "simply observing".

So, don't bother with it and as you well know, this will pass. Be well.

Answer (score 1):

Its a perfect situation if being sick. Actually you like to know dukkha to be able to escape form it. Pain is the very friend of a meditator.

Observe body, mind, feeling very often and spend a lot of time with it. Do not waste time to fight pain but stay with the breath, Mr./Mrs. 8CK8.

What the pain, where it comes from, if it really stays, where is ceases. The mood, the body... Spend your time with it and take the gift to have no other duty like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you would not focus on a thought like "Mindfulness is hard" when doing mindfulness meditation, then focusing on some other thought like "I am sick" while doing it would be counterproductive. I suffer from chronic pain, and while it is quite distracting, if I spent all my time focusing on it, I wouldn't get anything done. Part of mindfulness practice is acknowledging your passing thoughts and then letting them go.

Also remember that as Buddhists we practice the middle way. If you are really really sick, then you must take time for yourself to get better. Don't torture yourself by trying to do formal meditation.

Comment: "Don't *torture* yourself by trying to do formal meditation.", that is not the recommendation of the Buddha when sick and being mindful is something made in every posture. To care about the necessaries to maintain the body, is of course needed but to put Satipatthana on the highest place has more benefit as to simply cure another time or even not and having missed it.

Answer (score 0):

The Dukka in the sickness is the unpleasant feeling and sensations. Concrete on the arising and passing nature of these sensations. If you cannot see the arising and passing then their impermanence or changing nature.